# Extend Scaffolded DbContext to use IdentityDbContext

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

I'm using .NET8 RC2 Version along with EF Core and I scaffolded an Existing Database using **dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold** command.

This command generated Entities and a **AutoGeneratedDbContext**

I know I can extend its functionality by creating a Class which Inherits this DbContext like

```
public class CustomDbContext : AutoGeneratedDbContext
{
 public CustomDbContext()
 {
 }
 public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<AutoGeneratedDbContext> options) : base(options)
 {
 }
}
```

That works okay, but now I want to use Identity Authentication and for that I must add **IdentityDbContext**

Now if I create IdentityDbContext like this

```
public class IdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>(options)
{
}
```

then I'll have to Register one more DbContext which I think is not what I should be doing. And if I don't register IdentityDbContext then following will not work.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I know I can't do multi-inheritance with my CustomDbContext, that's why I'm a bit confused and don't know what to do next to make it a single DbContext with Identity

Comment: I think it is possible to inherit your `AutoGeneratedDbContext` from IdentityDbContext.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly reuse the `AutoGeneratedDbContext` to extend more functionality. But there is a trick here, you could try following:

1. I have a database "test02" contains a "Students" table
   [image]
2. Use database command to generate context "Test02Context" `Scaffold-DbContext "server=192.168.2.68;database=test02;user=mysql1;password=xxxxx" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -OutputDir Models`
   [image]
   3.In the "Test02Context" ,delete "OnModelCreating" "OnModelCreatingPartial" method. like below:

```
public partial class Test02Context : DbContext
{
    public Test02Context()
    {
    }

    public Test02Context(DbContextOptions<Test02Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
        => optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=test02;user=mysql1;password=xxxxx", Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("8.0.32-mysql"));
}
```

4.Use code-fisrt command to generate 1st migration file "initial"`Add-migration initial`.
[image]

5.In the "Test02Context", replace the `DbContext` with `IdentityDbContext`. And in the program.cs. Use this autogenerate context directly.

```
 Test02Context : IdentityDbContext
```

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Test02Context>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

6.Now generate the second migration `Add-migration second` After success, delete the first migration file . Then `Update-database` we will migration directly from second migration.
[image]
7. Check the database, the identity tables are updated.
[image]